# Workflow State for a child Item is Blank , will smart publish, publish the item

Tags: publishing

I Have a parent item with a workflow assigned to it and workflow state is approved and teo child items with workflows assigned to it

- Parent - Workflow assigned - State Approved

  - Child1 - Workflow assigned - State Approved
  - Child2 - Workflow Assigned - State  **Blank** (none)

Will Child2 be published if i do a smart publish on the parent item ? how does it work ?

Comment: If you perform a smart publish with sub items the item Child2 will also be published

Comment: @HishaamNamooya - thanks for the replay , how does it work ? , does the workflow state get inherited from parent? if the field is blank? , is that the default behaviour?

Comment: Previous comment is actual not true. It won't be published nor approved OOTB. You need to implement custom functionality to achieve it.

Comment: No, ootb sitecore, workflow is not inherited from parent item. You can implement custom code on save event to set the workflow state of the child items.

Comment: Take a look on blog post to help you out for now -> https://pageditor.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/approving-related-items-in-a-workflow/ . I will publish answer in the morning if nobody else adds it here in 12 hours :)

Comment: @PeterProchazka thanks for the reply , the problem that i have is ,we use Sitecore.ship smart publish from our CI environment , post deployment , it published Child2 as well , i want to know if that is Sitecore's default behaviour or is it a problem with Sitecore.ship smart publish

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: We use sitecore 8.1 u3

Comment: Do you use this command https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship/wiki/Publish? Ask maybe Kevin directly in Sitecore Ship repository

Comment: @PeterProchazka I got this fixed , the issue was due to the content editor logging in as admin and modified the content in experience editor , Admin user bypass workflow restrictions , so the content was published

Comment: @ManoharR.A Awesome. Congrats. Create answer with this fix.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally find the root Cause

When a content editor attempts to edit an item in the final state of a workflow, Sitecore creates a new version of the item and moves that item to the initial state of the workflow. None of that happens if you are logged in as an administrator. As an administrator, you can edit the content directly in the final state. Doing so means that these content changes are eligible to be published immediately, even if that isn't the intent.

As a rule of thumb, Sitecore administrator accounts should be not used for content entry because of these nuances.

in my case , the editor had logged onto the sitecore as admin and modified the item , which was not supposed to be published